# How to change the frame of UICollectionViewCell with slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uislider

I have a collectionView and a slider. Now I want to change the frame of collectionView cell when slider slides.
 I have searched through web but failed to get any idea.

Since I am a newbie so I am not getting any idea how can I do this.

Comment: Please post some code related to what all you have tried

Comment: Since I havent got any idea how to do that so I havent wrote any code for changing the frame. :( @Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a delegate method for the slider, and call it every time the slider is changed. Within the same function, you change the frame of the cell, based upon the value of your slider.

Comment: I havent came to know much about custom delegates. Can you help me by giving some codes plz? @Kunal